# Supress compiler errors caused by T4 template error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, t4

I have a T4 script that generates c# code in visual studio 2017.

When an error occurs while executing the T4 script, the generated .cs file only contains the text "ErrorGeneratingOutput".

This causes a gazillion subsequent compiler errors, because the rest of the code cannot find the classes defined in the generated code.

All these errors are shown in the visual studio error list, with the T4 errors somewhere in the middle, which makes it quite hard to find the actual culprit.

Can I hide all subsequent compiler and intellisense errors after a T4 code generation error occurs?

Or at least sort the errors so all T4 errors are always displayed first? (without changing the order of the other errors)